# Customising iOS InAppSettingsKit gives different results on iPhone compared to simulator

Tags: ios, inappsettingskit

I'm trying to change the background color of the InAppSettingKit view controller.

I've tried subclassing and overriding the cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [super tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    return cell;
}
```

I've tried creating a category for UIColor:

```
+ (UIColor *)groupTableViewBackgroundColor {
    return [UIColor redColor];
}
```

Whatever I try, the simulator shows the correct (expected) behaviour, but my iPhone shows the default group table background.

Any thoughts on how I can fix this?  Perhaps it's the way I'm creating an instance of my InAppSettingsViewController in my app delegate ...?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    IASKAppSettingsViewController *iaskvc = [[IASKAppSettingsViewController alloc] init];
    i = [UIImage imageNamed:@"20-gear-2.png"];
    [[iaskvc tabBarItem] setImage:i];
    [[iaskvc tabBarItem] setTitle:@"Settings"];

    // Create the Toolbar
    UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:iaskvc, nil];
    [tabBarController setViewControllers:viewControllers];

    [[self window] setRootViewController:tabBarController];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

XCode: Version 4.5.2 (4G2008a)
iOS deployment target: 5.1
iOS on iPhone: 6.0.1 (10A523)

[image: Simulator -- expected]
[image: iPhone -- customisation not working]

Comment: Have you tried deleting the application from your iPhone and re-deploying?

Comment: Yes, several times!  And I added new features (e.g. edit a title, change an icon) just to make sure I'd re-installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I found the answer after reading something else on SO, which made me think a little further.

Initialising my subclassed IASKAppSettingsViewController with:

```
MyAppSettingsViewController *iaskvc = [[MyAppSettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyAppSettingsViewController" bundle:nil];
```

and adding my own xib file (which previously I didn't have) allowed me to customise everything I needed, and it then worked fine on the iPhone.